# How to Enable ActiveX in Chrome?

Tags: windows, com, activex, google-chrome

I read that early builds of Chrome supported ActiveX, but was later restricted to certain MIME types (for support for say Windows Media Player).  I then read Google was going to enable ActiveX strictly for the Korean market.  How do I (re)enable this in Chrome?

Our web based product relies on ActiveX controls from 3rd parties to play custom video.  This limits us to IE.  We'd love to support Chrome also, but find it impossible w/o ActiveX support.

Comment: Instead of pushing your (3rd party) player at them, can you simply link or iframe the video and let the end user choose what player they want to use (e.g., by having it installed and configured for that mime type)? Then you'd be able to access the Mac and Linux markets, not to mention all of those Firefox users out there...

Comment: The ActiveX's we have are from 3rd party DVR manufacturers.  That is how they all release SDKs.  They are not cross platform, they do not have the source.  It's activex or the highway.

Comment: So it's a proprietary video format? Yuck.

Comment: Proprietary through and through, right down to their protocols.  All closed tight.

Comment: Right. Good luck with the ActiveX! :-)

Comment: I found the command line option --allow-all-activex but it didn't work for me. Everything I've found says Chrome doesn't support ActiveX.

Comment: Google is doing a Native Client plugin, which competes with ActiveX, so I wouldn't bet that Google has any plans to actively support ActiveX.

Comment: Supporting or using ActiveX is a huge blunder anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a [proprietary plugin called "Neptune"](http://www.meadroid.com/neptune/about.htm) which says that it will allow you to use IE Tab functionality in Chrome on Windows.

Meadroid do this because they have ActiveX controls which they have written and they want them to be able to work in any browser, and they explicitly mention Chrome in the list of supported browsers for enabling ActiveX with this.

There is also a modified version of Chrome, called [ChromePlus](http://www.chromeplus.org/), which includes IETab, among other extra features.

**I've not used either of these personally**, but they look like they'll do what you want.  I'd be interested to hear if they work out for you, as I know of other people who want to be able to use IEtab in Chrome  :)

Comment: Wow - that's like Chrome Frame in reverse. In this case why use Chrome at all - you'd just lose the piles of stuff from IE without gaining any performance.

Comment: @Keith : I think the point is that you get to use Chrome for 99% of what you do, and then IE for only the parts you have to (for ActiveX).  If you want to use IE for particular features then just use IE instead...

Comment: what about trying  steps mentioned in [this](http://support.myvisionexpress.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/444/0/how-to-activate-activex-for-google-chrome--firefox-for-single-sign-on-feature-for-rd-web-access) site, seems easy

Answer (score 9):

anyone who says activex is less secure then NPAPI is crazy.  They both allow the exact same access.  Yes I've written both.  The only reason people think activeX is insecure is because 10+ years ago IE had default settings that allowed a remote site to auto download the plugin.

Comment: Indeed. Bad defaults have ruined many a reputation throughout the years. Sometimes just cutting bait and rebranding is the best move

Answer (score 4):

maybe this new Chrome extension helps:

ActiveX for Chrome
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lgllffgicojgllpmdbemgglaponefajn/

Answer (score 2):

This could be pretty ugly, but doesn't Chrome use the [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) for plugins like Safari? In that case, you could write a wrapper plugin with the NPAPI that made the appropriate ActiveX creation and calls to run the plugin. If you do a lot of scripting against those plugins, you might have to be a bit of work to proxy those calls through to the wrapped ActiveX control.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but it sounds to me that this is something you could *only* do if you built the browser yourself - ie, not something done in a web page. I'm not sure that the sources for Chrome are publicly available (I think they are though), but the sources are what you'd probably need to change for this.

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but I don't think forking the Chrome browser and having customers install it would be received very well ;).

Comment: Yep, that is what I was trying to imply as well. Guess I'd check more carefully if my point is well explained next time.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Does_Google_Chrome_support_ActiveX

> Google Chrome comes with an ActiveX
>   shim, as part of its default plugin
>   array. So Google Chrome features at
>   least partial support for ActiveX
>   controls (as do many non-Internet
>   Explorer browsers). I can't find
>   information as to whether or not this
>   includes support for ActiveX security
>   certificates or the like, nor if/where
>   such plugins can be controlled, within
>   the browser.
>
> ..... Note that to enable the plug-in
>   you must run Chrome with the following
>   switch " --allow-all-activex" So in
>   shortcut that is used to start up
>   Chrome, add this after "Chrome.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this "IE Tab Multi" from Chrome. It works good! http://iblogbox.com/chrome/ietab/alert.php