# Using WScript.Shell to "Run" a script from a Chrome extension / Javascript

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript, activex

I am using this [AutoCopy chrome extension](http://www.chromeextensions.org/utilities/autocopy/) as a framework for what I hope to be my own working extension. Basically, I want my extension to be able to shell out another script (VBScript) on the users file system (sending a parameter for it, too, if I can get that to work) So, I was hoping to use something to the effect of:

```
wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wsh.run("myscriptiwannarun.vbs");
```

but it is unresponsive in my extension. (the code snippet works when run as a standalone .js file, however.)

Note I was however able to sneak in an `alert("test")` in the extensions code and it worked fine. So, it feels like something is amiss in creating the ActiveX object.

Am I unable to create ActiveX objects in a chrome extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

**[How to Enable ActiveX in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605946/how-to-enable-activex-in-chrome)**

Comment: Interesting. After more research, I'm compelled to NOT to use ActiveX from the browser...and instead move my vbscript component into the javscript world. I'm going to do some more analysis. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @itsazzad , How can I run a bat file in javascript for chrome?

Comment: @itsazzad , I found that `You are such a funny Genius`

Comment: @itsazzad I did a brute force search on google and stackoverflow and anywhere you think and then asked you, When you do not know sth it is better to be silent.